# Copy table row data to a form in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page which has a form/table.

I want to be able to click on a button at the end of a row, or the row itself and copy this data into another form on a separate html page, which can then be edited.

I know it probably has something to do with JQuery, however I have little to no experience with that.

If you require more details, I will happily provide.

EDIT:

Here is what it looks like now (it's a table which has retrieved data from an xml file using SimpleXML):

```
<form name ="editEvent" method="post" action="editEvent.php">
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#FFA500">
            <th>ID #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Picture Path</th>
            <th>Edit/Delete</th>
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1
          <td>Climbing</td>
          <td>09:00</td>
          <td>09:30</td>
          <td>Physical</td>
          <td>Description of what is going on</td>
          <td>where it is</td>
          <td>a photo link</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="edit" class ="box" value="Edit/Delete"/></td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
```

I want it to end up in a table like this:

```
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter new event name..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Enter event start time..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="endtime" placeholder="Enter event end time..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="category"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter a description of the event..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="loc"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="picturePath" placeholder="Enter link to picture..."/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="create" class="box" value="Create"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Honestly, any help or even pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.  I really don't know what to do here.  I've tried searching these forums and Google, but all I found is stuff on SQL and databases.  I just want to transfer some HTML table row data on one page to a HTML form on another to be edited.

Comment: Have you tried something yet ? Please post your code for users to help you.

Comment: A fiddle or some code of failed attempts would be very helpful

Comment: Anything that can help us?

Comment: Can you give the TR an ID? If so, use getElementByID (or jQuery, $("id")) and get the innerHtml and transfer that to your other form.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/J8KHn/1/
it still need some work though... like giving the field names and placeholder texts but those could be passed as <TD> attributes...

Answer (score 0):

You need some methods of identification on the columns like class name. For eg: `<td class="name">Climbing</td>` then you can attach an event handler on the `td` of the row and fetch all the data and populate the form.

```
$("td").on('click', function() {
   var tr = $(this).parent('tr');
   var name = tr.find(".name").text();
   // Grab other values like this

   // and later populate the form
});
```

However, Instead of copying the data, an efficient solution would be to hold the primary key of the row in one of the `td` or on one of the data attributes and use it to fetch the record from the database and then fill up the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for something like AngularJS (or KnockoutJS or Ember). It's better to bind your form fields to a model and then update the model (to automatically update the form) rather than manually copying over each value.

[This tutorial](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-copy-for-deep-copy) on AngularJS describes such a use case.